# Formatted Moment() Posted to Controller "loses" value

Tags: json, ajax, model-view-controller, momentjs

I am using `moment().startOf("week")` and `endOf("week")` to establish a date range that is then posted to a controller.  I am applying .format() to the value posted and the controller is expecting a DateTime.

In the Request Payload the JSON is formatted and the values are there.  At the controller, they are not.  See below.

What have I missed?  I have tried a few different things, sending just a date, not formatting and so on.

**Outgoing JSON**

```
var weekStart = moment().startOf("week").format();
var weekEnd = moment().endOf("week").format();

$.ajax({
 url: "/Timesheets/TaskHoursByPersonForCurrentWeek",
 type: "POST",
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json",
 data: JSON.stringify({personId: @User.FindFirst("Id").Value, ws: weekStart, we: weekEnd}),
 success: function (result){
    $('#cyearhours').append(result.total);
 },
 error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $("#toast-container").remove();
    toastr.options.positionClass = 'toast-top-full-width';
    toastr.options.timeOut = 10000;
    toastr.error("Fail:  We weren't able to get your hours for this week.");
 }
});
```

> {personId: 1, ws: "2017-02-19T00:00:00+00:00", we:
>   "2017-02-25T23:59:59+00:00"}

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> TaskHoursByPersonForCurrentWeek(int personId, DateTime ws, DateTime we)
{

var hours = await dbcontext.Timesheet
    .Where(t => !t.Deleted)
    .Where(t => t.PersonId == personId)
    .Where(t => t.TaskStart >= ws && t.TaskEnd < we )
    .GroupBy(t => t.PersonId)
    .Select(group => new
    {
        total = group.Sum(x => x.Minutes) / 60
    }).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    return Json(hours);
}
```

[image]